# Sharing .png with ShareCompat doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appcompat

so following this great article by Ian Lake - https://medium.com/google-developers/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b#.7rmkunfyi

I was able to successfully share either text or a .png from my app using ShareCompat.

This works fine, except when I share to gmail, the path to the image is added to the "to" field.  something like "//packagename/fileprovider/images/image.png"

As discussed at the bottom of the article, this can be fixed by removing 
intent.setData(data).  But this then breaks MMS and the native mail client.

I wonder if anyone can spot something I'm doing wrong.   The code works fine for most apps, Whatsapp, facebook, hangouts.

```
OutputStream outStream;

    File imageFile = new File(activity.getFilesDir(), name + ".png");
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.share_error_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    Uri uriToImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.DOCUMENT_PROVIDER, imageFile);

    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
            .setStream(uriToImage)
            .setType(activity.getContentResolver().getType(uriToImage))
            .getIntent();

    if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        activity.startActivity(shareIntent);
    }
```

Example of MMS app when I remove setData from the intent
[image]

and throws exception 
09-16 12:04:04.065 25012-25012/? W/Mms_UI_CMA: update sendbutton view
09-16 12:04:04.076 25012-25404/? E/Mms/image: initFromContentUri couldn't load image uri 
                                              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'mime_type' does not exist
                                                  at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:333)
                                                  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:87)
                                                  at com.android.mms.ui.UriImage.initFromContentUri(UriImage.java:222)
                                                  at com.android.mms.ui.UriImage.(UriImage.java:86)
                                                  at com.android.mms.model.ImageModel.initModelFromUri(ImageModel.java:94)
                                                  at com.android.mms.model.ImageModel.(ImageModel.java:76)
                                                  at com.android.mms.ui.SlideshowEditor.changeImage(SlideshowEditor.java:298)
                                                  at com.android.mms.ui.RichMessageEditor.internalChangeMedia(RichMessageEditor.java:666)
                                                  at com.android.mms.ui.RichMessageEditor.access$800(RichMessageEditor.java:103)
                                                  at com.android.mms.ui.RichMessageEditor$6.run(RichMessageEditor.java:549)
                                                  at com.android.mms.ui.AsyncDialog$ModalDialogAsyncTask.doInBackground(AsyncDialog.java:135)
                                                  at com.android.mms.ui.AsyncDialog$ModalDialogAsyncTask.doInBackground(AsyncDialog.java:87)
                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:307)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
09-16 12:04:04.079 25012-25404/? E/RichMessageEditor: internalChangeMedia:
                                                      com.google.android.mms.MmsException: Type of media is unknown.
                                                          at com.android.mms.model.ImageModel.initModelFromUri(ImageModel.java:98)
                                                          at com.android.mms.model.ImageModel.(ImageModel.java:76)
                                                          at com.android.mms.ui.SlideshowEditor.changeImage(SlideshowEditor.java:298)
                                                          at com.android.mms.ui.RichMessageEditor.internalChangeMedia(RichMessageEditor.java:666)
                                                          at com.android.mms.ui.RichMessageEditor.access$800(RichMessageEditor.java:103)
                                                          at com.android.mms.ui.RichMessageEditor$6.run(RichMessageEditor.java:549)
                                                          at com.android.mms.ui.AsyncDialog$ModalDialogAsyncTask.doInBackground(AsyncDialog.java:135)
                                                          at com.android.mms.ui.AsyncDialog$ModalDialogAsyncTask.doInBackground(AsyncDialog.java:87)
                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:307)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
09-16 12:04:04.091 891-902/? I/art: Object allocation is busy now, so prior to grow the heap. New heap size is 91 MB

Comment: "this can be fixed by removing intent.setData(data)" -- you are not supposed to use `setData()` with `ACTION_SEND`. "But this then breaks MMS and the native mail client" -- please explain in detail what the nature of the problem is.

Comment: updated with image

Comment: Check LogCat for error messages from that app. You might need to apply [my `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#supporting-legacy-apps) (or the equivalent) to try to overcome buggy clients. I demonstrate using that with `FileProvider` in a few sample apps, such as [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider).

Comment: ahh, stupid of me not to have looked at logs outside of my own app

Comment: Yeah, use `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper` to fix that.